# Exit out of a Google Form without submitting

Tags: google-forms

I have a registration form for an event where the participants must meet a certain condition.

Section One has a question asking if the participant meets the condition. If they answer "yes", they are taken to the section where registration begins.

If they answer "no", they are taken to a section that explains the necessity and includes a link for more information.

I would like for the form to "end" at this point. There would be no answers submitted.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

SusieG